# Swift 4 Parse Server Cloud Code Error

Tags: ios, swift, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

I simply copied and pasted the sample code from the docs

```
        // Swift
    PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("averageRatings", withParameters: ["movie":"The Matrix"]) {
        (response: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        let ratings = response as? Float
        // ratings is 4.5
    }
```

I get the following error from Xcode

```
Cannot convert value of type '(AnyObject?, NSError?) -> Void' to expected argument type 'PFIdResultBlock?' (aka 'Optional<(Optional<Any>, Optional<Error>) -> ()>')
Insert ' as! PFIdResultBlock'
```

If I click fix and insert `as! PFIdResultBlock` the error remains and still says to add `as! PFIdResultBlock`